# Can't get da Vinci resolve to open on 23.10

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, davinci-resolve, 23.10

I've been using resolve on kububtu for years. I updated to 23.10 from 23.04 yesterday and today I tried to launch resolve and it wouldn't open.

My first idea was to completely uninstall and reinstall the latest version from their website. Still won't open. Is there some additional packages I need to install? Or am I going to have to go back to 23.04 or what?

PC specs:
Amd 3700x CPU
Nvidia 2060 super

Screenshot from Ksystemlog that might help diagnose the problem:
[image: Screenshot]

Resolve crash logs:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mBvOSw53ol4OKQfebgwogjuUzN_x80dx/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: It's askubuntu not askkubuntu so it's not this site's topic

Comment: Thank you. 

Comment: @NoOne Not true. All supported official flavors are welcome

Comment: Really ? So let me know what are they

Comment: Sorry first last

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 /opt/resolve/libs/
```

Hope this works

Comment: Can anyone confirm this fixes the problem? I did not upgrade but had  a clean install and cannot find a way to start it, would really want to find a solution.